# Why does this code insert a blank row between two rows written (C# Excel Interop)?

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-interop, listobject

In my C# (.NET 4.5) Windows Forms app using Excel Interop, I adapted the code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxks80sb(v=vs.100).aspx) like so (removing redundant things grayed out by Resharper, and add "Type." before the "missing" args (and changing their case to upper):

```
private void WriteListObjectTestSheet()
{
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[5, 1] = "Apple";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[6, 1] = "Strawberry";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[7, 1] = "Cashew";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[8, 1] = "Kumquat";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[9, 1] = "Pomegranate";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[10, 1] = "Banana";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[11, 1] = "Pineapple";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[12, 1] = "Kiwi";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[13, 1] = "Huckleberry";
    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[14, 1] = "Gooseberry";

    Excel.ListObject fruitList =
        _xlSheetPlatypus.
            ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
                _xlSheetPlatypus.Range[
                    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[4, 1],
                    _xlSheetPlatypus.Cells[4, 1]], 
                Type.Missing, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo);
}
```

The ListObject is added at row 4, column 1 (or "A") as desired, and the "fruits" are written into the cells, but not starting at row 5 (where "Apple" should be) but at row 6, as you can see here (unwanted blank row highlighted):

[image]

There may be a (a lot more) to it, but this may be at least part of the reason why the ListObject has no idea what to sort and filter, as evidenced by the options it affords when it is clicked as seen here:

[image]

Why is a blank row 5 added, and how can I prevent that?

Comment: The range supplied to the ListObjects.Add method is 4 - 4. Try changing it to 5 - 14?

Comment: When you create a `ListObject` from a range and saying the table has no header, It shifts the range one row down and add a `Column1` cell. In the above code you said create a table from [4,1] to [4,1] and you said you have no headers, So it creats a table with one row and adds a `Column1` header and shifts all things 1 row down. So the result is what you said to excel do for you. You can correct it by specifying the correct range and saying you have a header. I posted an answer based on this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `ListObject` from a range and saying the table has no header, It shifts the range one row down and add a `Column1` cell.

In the above code you said create a table from `[4,1]` to `[4,1]` and you said the table has no headers, So it creates a table with one row and adds a `Column1` header and shifts all things 1 row down. So the result is what you said to excel to do for you.

You can correct it by specifying the correct range and saying you have a header.

In the below code, I first add a `Header` at `[4,1]` and then add fruits and at last create the list from `[4, 1]` to `[14, 1]`, and saying the table has headers. So it keeps my header.

```
using XL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XL.Application application = new XL.Application();
    application.Visible = true;
    XL.Workbook book = application.Workbooks.Add();
    XL.Worksheet sheet = (XL.Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];
    sheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Header";
    sheet.Cells[5, 1] = "Apple";
    sheet.Cells[6, 1] = "Strawberry";
    sheet.Cells[7, 1] = "Cashew";
    sheet.Cells[8, 1] = "Kumquat";
    sheet.Cells[9, 1] = "Pomegranate";
    sheet.Cells[10, 1] = "Banana";
    sheet.Cells[11, 1] = "Pineapple";
    sheet.Cells[12, 1] = "Kiwi";
    sheet.Cells[13, 1] = "Huckleberry";
    sheet.Cells[14, 1] = "Gooseberry";

    XL.ListObject fruitList = 
        sheet.ListObjects.Add(XL.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
            sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[4, 1], sheet.Cells[14, 1]], 
                Type.Missing, XL.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Reza! You remind me of a fractal, because you excel at Excel.