# How can I specify the cell location of a ListObject (sort/filter) control in a C# Excel Interop app?

Tags: c#, filter, filtering, excel-interop, listobject

I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096568/why-does-this-code-insert-a-blank-row-between-two-rows-written-c-excel-interop) how to add a "ListObject" (I think of it as a "Sort/Filter Control") to an Excel spreadsheet. Here's a simplistic example of how to accomplish it:

```
// add the data
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[1, 1] = "Marionberry";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[2, 1] = "Apple";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[3, 1] = "Strawberry";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[4, 1] = "Cashew";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[5, 1] = "Kumquat";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[6, 1] = "Pomegranate";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[7, 1] = "Banana";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[8, 1] = "Pineapple";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[9, 1] = "Kiwi";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[10, 1] = "Huckleberry";
_xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[11, 1] = "Gooseberry";

// create a Sort/Filter Control for the data above
Excel.ListObject fruitList =
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.
        ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
            _xlSheetListObjectTest.Range[
                _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[1, 1],
                _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[11, 1]],
            Type.Missing, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo);
```

This puts the "ListObject" directly above the populated cells, as can be seen here:

[image]

And here's how it looks with that ListObject dropped down:

[image]

That's awesome functionality (a lot of bang for only a little bit of code) for that sort of reqirement. However, I have a sheet that contains columns of month data, with a requirement to filter out selected month columns (sorting is unneeded and unwanted). Here's how it looks when several months have been selected when generating the report:

[image]

But the user can generate reports with fewer months in it (as few as 1, as many as 13), such as:

[image]

So I want a "ListObject" whose range of filtering operation spans the data for the months being displayed (many rows, many columns), with the ability for the user to then deselect certain months, hiding the entire row[s] of deselected months.

However, with this code, which defines the range of all month data:

```
Excel.ListObject monthFilterControl = // Resharper complains that this is not used (grays out "monthFilterControl"), but this is what creates the control
    _xlSheet.
        ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
            _xlSheet.Range[
                _xlSheet.Cells[COLUMN_HEADING_ROW, MONTH1_COL],
                _xlSheet.Cells[_xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, _xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1]],
            Type.Missing, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo);
```

The problem is that multiple ListObjects elbow their way right onto the month header columns, pushing down the rows beneath them, misaligning the rows. Not only that, what they offer to sort and filter doesn't meet my tough standards. Instead of allowing me to filter out entire month columns, it does this:

[image]

So what I want is:

```
There should only be one ListObject control in a single cell a row above the month columns, not one in every month header cell.
A Filter list (array of checkboxes) of all Months; deselecting "September" would cause that month column to hide, etc.
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: It's not possible to have an auto filter in a row that shows values from multiple columns (Or in other word, You can't have auto filter based on values of a row.) 

Auto filter only works on values of a column.

**As an option** 

You can copy your cells, and paste them using `Transpose` option. It inverts your table and convert columns to rows, and also changes formulas to work as expected. Know you can apply filter on first column (Previously known  as your first row)

Comment: **As another option** If you have raw data in your C# application You can perform such filtering in your C# application and then export only desired columns to the excel file.

Comment: Yes, I can do all this filtering with C# and LINQ, but I can't make changes on the fly in the .xlsx file. It's "cast in stone" at that point. I needs some sort of functionality that allows me to hide columns via user interaction. Is that impossible, then?

Comment: It's hard to say something is Impossible. But I as far as I know you can't do it simply using standard and straightforward features. Maybe you can try writing some macro to do such job. But I don't recommend :)

Comment: If the Excel Whisperer recommends against it, who am I to argue?

Comment: :)) Your modesty! Hope you receive better answers :)